# Text file from resource file

Tags: vb6, text-files, embedded-resource

I have a text file which I want to include in the resource file in my project

Right now I have included the text file via "Add Custom Resource".

When I run the project I read out the file from the resource file and save it to a tempory file.

```
LoadDataIntoFile "TXT", App.Path & "\temp.txt"
```

This uses the following function

```
Public Sub LoadDataIntoFile(DataName As String, FileName As String)
  Dim myArray() As Byte
  Dim myFile As Long
  If Dir(FileName) = "" Then
    myArray = LoadResData(DataName, "CUSTOM")
    myFile = FreeFile
    Open FileName For Binary Access Write As #myFile
    Put #myFile, , myArray
    Close #myFile
  End If
End Sub
```

Next, when I need the text file data I read in the temporay file

```
'read complete text file
intFile = FreeFile
Open strFile For Input As #intFile
  strData = Input(LOF(intFile), #intFile)
Close #intFile
```

I then can use the data from the text file without any problems.

It seems a bit awkward though to first read the data, then save to file, and then read the data from file

Is there a way to inlcude a text file in the resource file, and read it directly into a string variable when I need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

Reading the text file from the resource file returns an array of bytes.

To convert this array of bytes into a string I use:

```
strData = StrConv(myArray, vbUnicode)
```

I am not sure if it is the best way, but it does work :)